# Mapbox Marker Cluster with custom cluster icon

Tags: mapbox, markerclusterer

I'm using Mapbox for a Phonegap app and making use of the Marker Cluster plugin to cluster our pins. Customizing the icon for a marker is easy enough, but I'd also like to be able to customize the cluster icon. I'm not seeing a way to customize the cluster icon. Suggestions?

Here's a snippet of what I have so far:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('mapView', 'myMap.mapCode', { zoomControl: false }).setView([geoData.lat, geoData.lon], 5),
    markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

var propertyCount = properties.length;
for (var i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++) {
    var property = properties[i];

    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(property.lat, property.lon), {
        icon: markerIcon,
        title: property.heading
    });

    marker.bindPopup(property.heading);
    markers.addLayer(marker);
}

map.addLayer(markers);
```

Comment: Nothing like asking a question to find an answer. Turns out customizing the icon is documented on the MarkerCluster github page: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

Answer (score 0):

You can define the marker like so:

```
var cluster = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<b>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</b>' });
    }
});
```

which will allow you to style it however you wish.